# Images covering right side bar

Tags: bug, design, images, list

When in a list, adding a picture that is indented covers up the background on the right where links normally go. See picture below:

[image]

(source: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/6446/9628)

As you can see, with multiple indents, the image is mixing with the links on the right, making some hard to read. I think it would be better if images were forced to be to the far left, instead of indenting them with the rest of the text.

Comment: Sorry @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ. Posted the link to the question.

Comment: One of the oldest bugs around, and doesn't look like it's going to be fixed.

Comment: Didn't see that post, thanks

Comment: No worry, happens to the best.